# Toggle button description when each toggle does somtehing different?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, users, ux-designer

So I have three toggle buttons, disabled, enabled, and emergency only. For the scope of this question, its not important what this toggle button does, but more the fact that each toggle has a slightly different function. Disable/enable can be solved with a single description, but the emergency only might need some clarification on what that does since it has a slightly different function that might not be 100% clear. Would it make sense to put the description of the "emergency" toggle since it may be unclear, or should I put the disable/enable description since that gives a general idea of what this does. Is there a way I can incorporate both?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should a multi-state toggle slider with more than two states be implemented?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75399/how-should-a-multi-state-toggle-slider-with-more-than-two-states-be-implemented)

Answer (score 1):

Group "Enable" and "Disable" buttons by slightly separating the "Emergency only" button, and add the description, justified right.

[image: Mock-up]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Garik, it's better to divide the toggle button into two groups.

In addition, you can use another component, for example, a regular toggle and a button.  I also advise you to read a very good article by Taras https://uxdesign.cc/selection-controls-ui-component-series-3badc0bdb546